# Kmeans going exceptionally slow when clustering more than 3 documents

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, document, k-means

I'm trying to use kmeans to cluster similar documents to each other.

I am using NLTK's KMeans.

When I only cluster 3 documents, it takes less than 5 seconds. But once I add in a fourth document, it doesn't finish (I cut it out after 10 minutes).

When there are 4 documents, the vector size is about 1000. The vectors are sparse too, but I have 8 gigs of RAM, so I'm not worried about that. 1000 shouldn't be that much.

Anyone have any ideas why it solves 3 documents in 5 seconds, but can't solve 4 documents...at least in 10 minutes before giving up? When I go into production, it will theoretically have to cluster 300 or 400 documents at a time.

I was thinking of trying a different kmeans library to see if the NLTK implementation is weak, but I don't want to waste my effort if I'm the problem.

Thanks all.

Comment: You should atleast provide code of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Pycluster library and it works now.